# How to raise an AttributeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, attributeerror, raise

I am trying to raise an `AttributeError` for unit testing but could not succeed. The problem is the error is not raised.

```
import unittest
class TestErrors(unittest.TestCase):
    """Unit testing of errors"""
    def test_get_it(self):
        """Error tests for get_it"""
        with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
            get_it_tester("Foo", "Bar")
```

The code for `get_it_tester`:

```
def get_it_tester(path, cont):
    """Tester function for get_it"""
    files = glob.glob(f"{path}{os.sep}i*")
    files += glob.glob(f"{path}{os.sep}i*{os.sep}{cont}*")
    return get_it(files)
```

The code for `get_it`:

```
def get_it(files):
    """Get a list of iterations"""
    try:
        return [int(re.search(f"{os.sep}i([0-9]+)", f).groups(0)[0]) for f in files]
    except AttributeError:
        print(f"ERROR: The path must be in format of 'path{os.sep}to{os.sep}i1'")
```

Comment: Why do you think an exception will be raised and why do you think it should be an `AttributeError`?

Comment: `print` does not raise an error. You are catching the `AttributeError` if it occurs and printing the result.

Comment: `get_it` does raise an `AttributeError`, but you immediately catch it and print an error message instead. The exception never leaves the function, so as far as your test is concerned, it was never raised.

Comment: This is the same question as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852127/how-to-raise-a-shutil-samefileerror), and the answer is also the same - if you catch the exception in your code without re-rasing it, you cannot catch it in the test. Also of course, if your code does not raise it in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_it(files):
    """Get a list of iterations"""
    try:
        return [int(re.search(f"{os.sep}i([0-9]+)", f).groups(0)[0]) for f in files]
    except AttributeError:
        print(f"ERROR: The path must be in format of 'path{os.sep}to{os.sep}i1'")
        raise
```

Comment: Would be a better answer with words to explain it, but I agree this is one of the likelier possibilities of what the asker wanted.

Comment: It did not work as expected. Same result.